# Testing an ArrayList .txt file for errors (not fitting the allowed format)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java program that reads a .txt file and is able to determine if the content format is correct. The file should have 12 lines with 2 integers each. I need to test for the following things:

- If it has too many integers per line
- If it doesn't have enough integers per line
- If it includes doubles instead of ints
- If it includes strings instead of ints

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextFileReader {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> inputFile = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
      Scanner fileScanner = null;
      try {
         fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("perfect_file.txt"));
         while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            inputFile.add(fileScanner.nextInt());
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Error reading generic answers, program ending.");
         System.exit(1);
      }
      fileScanner.close();

      for (int i = 0; i < inputFile.size(); i++) {
         if (inputFile.size() > 12) {

         }
      }

      if (inputFile.size() > 12) {
         System.out.println("Error: Lines exceed 12");
      }
      if (inputFile.size() < 12) {
         System.out.println("Error: Not enough lines");
      }

      System.out.println(inputFile);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few points:

1) Use a try with resources statement as that will automatically close any resources for you (so will call `fileScanner.close()` for you. At the minute, if there is an exception thrown the `close()` method is never called because you're stopping the JVM from running. An alternative to the try with resources is to keep it the way you have it but put your `close()` in a `finally` block

```
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("perfect_file.txt"))) {

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error reading generic answers, program ending.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

2) If you call `fileScanner.nextInt()` and the next line isn't an integer then it will throw a `InputMismatchException` so an easier approach is to scan the line as a String and check the String for more control... Here's where you can check most of your conditions from above

```
   List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        byte lineCount = 0;
        try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("perfect_file.txt"))) {
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                lineCount++;
                if (line.length() != 2) {
                    System.err.println("Line " + (lineCount + 1) + " has the wrong number of digits. Expected 2. Got: " + line.length());
                } else {
                    try {
                        ints.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.err.println("Line " + (lineCount + 1) + " doesn't " +
                                "contain valid integers. Input: \"" + line + "\" - skipping line");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading generic answers, program ending.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

3) (trivial) Your length checks can be done in 1 statement

```
if (inputFile.size() != 12) {
            System.out.println((inputFile.size() < 12 ? "Error: Not enough lines" : "Error: Too many lines")
                                + ". Expected 12. Got " + inputFile.size());
        }
```